# The trait `raw_window_handle::HasRawDisplayHandle` is not implemented for `Window`

Tags: rust, window, wgpu-rs, winit

When I try to make a wgpu surface I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Window: raw_window_handle::HasRawDisplayHandle` is not satisfied
    --> src/lib.rs:34:56
     |
34   |         let surface = unsafe { instance.create_surface(&window) }.unwrap();
     |                                         -------------- ^^^^^^^ the trait `raw_window_handle::HasRawDisplayHandle` is not implemented for `Window`
     |                                         |
     |                                         required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `raw_window_handle::HasRawDisplayHandle`:
               &'a T
               raw_window_handle::borrowed::DisplayHandle<'_>
```

this my code:

`let surface = unsafe { instance.create_surface(&window) }.unwrap();`

i dont know how fix that, i try fix but everything is in vain.

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function `create_surface` takes an argument `window` which must implement `HasRawWindowHandle + HasRawDisplayHandle`

Your code is correct, but you are missing a/the `winit **rwh_05**` feature.

Replace `winit = "0.29"` with `winit = { version = "0.29", features = ["rwh_05"]}` in the `Cargo.toml` file and it should work.

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly correct. Although, I hear lots of talk of part of the wonder of cargo taking care of dependencies for you. Is there a cargo way of resolving this automatically? like telling cargo to use all features or something